# 'Angular could not be found' when integrating Travis/Sauce Labs

Tags: angularjs, protractor, travis-ci, saucelabs

I'm working to get Travis CI to run Protractor tests using Sauce Labs. The tunneling works fine, and my Express server clearly starts and stays up at `http://localhost:9000`, but my Protractor tests quickly fail with the error `Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:9000/ : retries looking for angular exceeded`. All the suggestions on the Internet usually involve not using Angular 1.0 (using 1.3), extending time outs (doing that), or forcing Protractor to look at `<html>` for the ng-app directive (doing that). I'm out of ideas.

Relevant config:

### protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',

specs: ['e2e/**/*.spec.js'],
framework: 'jasmine',
maxSessions: 1,
allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
rootElement: 'html',
multiCapabilities: [
    {'browserName': 'chrome'},
    {'browserName': 'firefox'},
    {'name': 'diplomacy'},
    {'tunnel-identifier': process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER ? process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER : null},
    {'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER ? process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER : null}
],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
    includeStackTrace: true
}
}
```

### main.spec.js

```
'use strict';

describe('Home page', function() {
    var page;

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
    });

    it('should pass', function() {
         expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

### Travis log

Go [here](https://travis-ci.org/spamguy/diplomacy/builds/53552624) for the complete log. The highlights:

```
Extracting Sauce Connect
Waiting for Sauce Connect readyfile
08 Mar 16:30:00 - Sauce Connect 4.3.6, build 1628 8a5c837
08 Mar 16:30:00 - Using CA certificate bundle /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
08 Mar 16:30:00 - Starting up; pid 3519
08 Mar 16:30:00 - Command line arguments: sc-4.3.6-linux//bin/sc -i 42.1 -f sauce-connect-ready-21801 -l /home/travis/sauce-connect.log
08 Mar 16:30:00 - Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
08 Mar 16:30:00 - Resolving saucelabs.com to 162.222.73.28 took 17 ms.
08 Mar 16:30:01 - Started scproxy on port 37246.
08 Mar 16:30:01 - Please wait for 'you may start your tests' to start your tests.
08 Mar 16:30:01 - Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
08 Mar 16:30:11 - Secure remote tunnel VM provisioned.
08 Mar 16:30:11 - Tunnel ID: 3cc5fd5b59984957831d125617c7d4f6
08 Mar 16:30:11 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: booting
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: running
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Remote tunnel host is: maki76159.miso.saucelabs.com
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Resolving maki76159.miso.saucelabs.com to 162.222.76.159 took 48 ms.
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Starting Selenium listener...
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
08 Mar 16:30:14 - Selenium listener started on port 4445.
08 Mar 16:30:16 - Sauce Connect is up, you may start your tests.
08 Mar 16:30:16 - Connection established.
```

[unit tests here...all passing!]

```
[chrome #1] PID: 3621
[chrome #1] Specs: /home/travis/build/spamguy/diplomacy/e2e/main/main.spec.js
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1] Using SauceLabs selenium server at http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
[chrome #1] [31mF[0m
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1] Failures:
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1]   1) Home page should pass
[chrome #1]    Message:
[chrome #1]      [31mError: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:9000/ : retries looking for angular exceeded[0m
[chrome #1]    Stacktrace:
[chrome #1]      Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:9000/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
[chrome #1] ==== async task ====
[chrome #1] Protractor.get(http://localhost:9000/) - test for angular
[chrome #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/spamguy/diplomacy/e2e/main/main.spec.js:7:13)
[chrome #1] ==== async task ====
[chrome #1] Asynchronous test function: beforeEach()
[chrome #1] Error
[chrome #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/spamguy/diplomacy/e2e/main/main.spec.js:6:3)
[chrome #1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/spamguy/diplomacy/e2e/main/main.spec.js:3:1)
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1] Finished in 11.877 seconds
[chrome #1] [31m1 test, 2 assertions, 1 failure
[0m[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1] SauceLabs results available at http://saucelabs.com/jobs/c0eed61d95044f77b200a7b21d2443a3

[launcher] 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
```

[two more WebDriver instances fail with similar errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I eventually got everything working correctly. There is no 'one fix' I made so I can't really clarify the solution easily. The following files are [from my repository with which I set up continuous integration](https://github.com/spamguy/diplomacy).

#### protractor-travis.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    // sauce plz
    sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
    sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',

    specs: ['e2e/**/*.po.js', 'e2e/**/*.spec.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    maxSessions: 1,
    allScriptsTimeout: 40000,
    getPageTimeout: 40000,
    rootElement: 'html',
    multiCapabilities: [
        capabilitiesForBrowser('chrome', '41'),
        capabilitiesForBrowser('firefox'),
        capabilitiesForBrowser('safari')
    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
        includeStackTrace: true
    }
};

function capabilitiesForBrowser(browserName, browserVersion) {
    var capabilities = {
        'browserName': browserName,
        'build': process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER,
        'name': 'dipl.io'
    };
    if (browserVersion)
        capabilities.version = browserVersion;

    return capabilities;
}
```

#### Gruntfile.js

```
protractor: {
        travis: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'protractor-travis.conf.js',
                args: {
                    sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
                    sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY
                }
            }
        },
        local: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'protractor-local.conf.js'
                //,debug: true
            }
        }
    }
```

#### .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.12'
services:
    - mongodb
env:
  global:
    - secure: ioYHs4gjuL9iuwxamtKCkERvvSiBlAgxhLZ1Ry4xrZhNWe3e4pett3249hWovDYzG/eEHTA20/NDvZ1JIMYODFzY4gURVHNtUkoYNokLSDguTH1OPXGMmtQzJGersxYQOjRj3gSss7Z0joUrcfPQJsG1Vt0eHR/ewN7Qbm8NBn0=
    - secure: NH3WbHM2Ir95csdWAdd7/ISYVvnYFQe7Rv4rCoYu9V6V2M9AzlARYTAvBqoK7PdD/RV0KR41t6OVeUxBVhuzT26NvBVZVyLcvfjK29AoKCDCU7VD7nQa/RQ9KyDr5DAHfyQQ5AQMhsla5qPTaFZb82F83lL44nDzrvYzE8CEaGw=

before_install:
    - npm install -g bower
    - bower install
    - sed -i 's/git@github.com:/https:\/\/github.com\//' .gitmodules
    - git submodule update --init --recursive
    - npm install -g grunt-cli

script:
    - grunt test:protractor-travis
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem here. Except here's a difference:

When I start up a SauceConnect tunnel manually, as described here:
https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/sauce-connect/#when-should-i-use-sauce-connect-

Then everything runs smoothly, and my build passses.

But I don't want to have to start up SauceConnect manually every time, I want that to happen automatically during the build process. So I updated the travis.yml file as instructed here:

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sauce-connect/

In this case, the tunnel is opened automatically. Here's a bit of the log, too long to paste all, but I can assure you that the tunnel is opened.

```
Starting Sauce Connect
25.96s$ travis_start_sauce_connect
Using temp dir /tmp/sc.hHct
/tmp/sc.hHct ~/build/Diobox/diobox_stateful
Downloading Sauce Connect
--2015-06-11 17:13:21--  http://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3.6-linux.tar.gz
Resolving saucelabs.com (saucelabs.com)... 162.222.73.28
Connecting to saucelabs.com (saucelabs.com)|162.222.73.28|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

....

```
11 Jun 17:13:23 - Starting up; pid 3524
11 Jun 17:13:23 - Command line arguments: sc-4.3.6-linux//bin/sc -i 25.1 -f sauce-connect-ready-29337 -l /home/travis/sauce-connect.log
11 Jun 17:13:23 - Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
11 Jun 17:13:23 - Resolving saucelabs.com to 162.222.73.28 took 1 ms.
11 Jun 17:13:24 - ***********************************************************
11 Jun 17:13:24 - A newer version of Sauce Connect (build 1671) is available!
11 Jun 17:13:24 - Download it here:
11 Jun 17:13:24 - https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3.8-linux.tar.gz
11 Jun 17:13:24 - ***********************************************************
11 Jun 17:13:24 - Started scproxy on port 50965.
11 Jun 17:13:24 - Please wait for 'you may start your tests' to start your tests.
11 Jun 17:13:24 - Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
11 Jun 17:13:24 - Shutting down named tunnel 25.1 (b7f004bfd8174ac6be612082b1654367).
11 Jun 17:13:32 - Secure remote tunnel VM provisioned.
11 Jun 17:13:32 - Tunnel ID: 6f295a34dfe14b639b78438e59307ae3
11 Jun 17:13:32 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: booting
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: running
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Remote tunnel host is: maki78107.miso.saucelabs.com
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Resolving maki78107.miso.saucelabs.com to 162.222.78.107 took 8 ms.
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Starting Selenium listener...
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
11 Jun 17:13:46 - Selenium listener started on port 4445.
11 Jun 17:13:47 - Sauce Connect is up, you may start your tests.
11 Jun 17:13:47 - Connection established.
```

But then once the connection is opened, and build gets to the point where tests should be running, I get the same Angular errors you listed above.